# Charts on rails 3 using highcharts

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I am following [chapter 223 (charts) of the railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=charts)  and was trying to implement the "donut" style for an application using the [Highcharts library](http://www.highcharts.com).
I now know that they're just one "pie" series inside another and each one of them with its own data source.

Although, when trying to adjust the examples to what I wanted I just couldn't get the desired result.I was wondering which is the right way to pass data to the "data" parameter of the chart?.

So I copied from the internet the next code (just for testing):

```
      series: [       
      {
        type: 'pie',
        name: '2008',
        size: '45%',
        innerSize: '20%',
        data: [
            { name: 'Firefox', y: 45.0, color: '#4572A7' },
            { name: 'IE', y: 26.8, color: '#AA4643' },
            { name: 'Chrome', y: 12.8, color: '#89A54E' },
            { name: 'Safari', y: 8.5, color: '#80699B' },
            { name: 'Opera', y: 6.2, color: '#3D96AE' },
            { name: 'Mozilla', y: 0.2, color: '#DB843D' }      
           ]             
       }
      ]
```

Other way is passing data as:

```
series: [       
       {
        type: 'pie',
        name: '2008',
        size: '45%',
        innerSize: '20%',
 data: [
        ['IE', 46.6],
        ['Chrome',  3.1], 
        ['Safari',  2.7], 
        ['Opera',  2.3],
        ['Mozilla', 0.4]           
     ]
   }]
```

As you can see, the data I'm using is static.**What if I want to use information from my db?**.
So,since I have a couple of models:

```
class Frame < ActiveRecord::Base       class FrString < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :total           attr_accessible :frame_id,:name,:total

   has_many :fr_strings                   belongs_to :frame
end                                    end
```

I though creating an array of arrays to eventually use it as datasource for my charts would be a good idea....not so good apparently.

```
<% _data=[] %>
<%Frame.all.each do |frame|%>
   <% _data  << [frame.name,frame.fr_strings.sum(:total)]%>
<%end%>
```

The pie is no ploting.So I would appreciate any help on this matter

**Edit (Javascript output)**

When I pass the "data" parameter as:

```
  data: [                
         <%_data.each do |d|%>
            <%=d%>,
          <%end%>                   
     ]
```

It gives me:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
  <html> 
    <head> 
     <title>Charts</title> 
      <link href="/stylesheets/application.css?1305016385" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
     <script src="/javascripts/application.js?1304963001" type="text/javascript">       </script> 
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js?1305020819" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1305020831" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="/javascripts/highcharts.js?1305029094" type="text/javascript"></script> 

  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/> 
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="G4k7DrZNfIcJt4Dlbz7JzNViSjQ+OGPUAVY4rW+XAxY="/> 
  </head> 
<body> 
       <script type="text/javascript" charset='utf-8'> 
           $(function(){
         new Highcharts.Chart({         
           chart: {
          renderTo: 'frames_chart',
          margin: [50, 0, 0, 0],
          plotBackgroundColor: 'none',
          plotBorderWidth: 0,
          plotShadow: false            
       },
       title: {
          text: 'CHART TITLE'
       },
        subtitle: {
          text: 'Inner circle: 2008, outer circle: 2010'
       },
       tooltip: {
          formatter: function() {
             return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+ 
                this.point.name +': '+ this.y +' %';
          }
       },
        series: [      
        {
          type: 'pie',
          name: '2008',
          size: '60%',
          innerSize: '10%',
          data: [
               [&quot;Car&quot;, 93.0]
               [&quot;House&quot;, 91.0]
          ],
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
             }
          },           
        ]
     });
  });
</script> 

     <div id="frames_chart" style="width:560px; height:300px"></div> 

 </body> 
</html>
```

Could that syntaxis `"&quot; **** &quot;"` be what's messing things up here?.I rechecked the _data array and that's how it's being filled.Maybe the issue concerns to how I'm retrieving data?

Comment: What does the generated javascript source look like after that rails code runs?

Comment: @NT3RP-I added a "Edit" section with the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you get in html is just not a valid JavaScript code and is not interpreted. Try the following:

```
 data: [                
     <%_data.each do |d|%>
        <%=raw d %>,
      <%end%>                   
 ]
```

The raw directive should remove the &quot html code you're seeing for quotes.

If that's not helping, can you check whether you have any javascript errors using a browser extension? For Google Chrome, you can go to Tools -> Developer tools and see if you have any js errors in your page.

Edit: You may also need to mark 'd' as html_safe, like that:

```
 data: [                
     <%_data.each do |d|%>
        <%=raw d.html_safe %>,
      <%end%>                   
 ]
```

Comment: <%raw d%> did it for me!.When using html_safe wouldn't work cause there's no html_safe method for my d variable (it only applies to string variables AFAIK).But thanks for taking the time.Now it plots the results!!.